# Stuck on an example of why a Matrix lie algebra needs to be closed with respect to GL(n,C)

Tags: lie-groups

Can someone please help me on this example.

$$
G = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} { e }^{ it } & 0 \\ 0 & { e }^{ 2\pi it } \end{pmatrix},\quad t\in\mathbb{R}  \right\} 
$$

G is a matrix group, but not a matrix Lie group, why not?

I cannot think of a sequence which is in G and converges in GL(n,C) but not in G.

Thank you in advance.

Harch

Comment: Do you believe that the set $\{e^{2\pi i(2n+1)\pi}\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ contains points arbitrarily close to $-1$? (More generally that the set $\{e^{\pi i an} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}$ is dense in $S^1$ when $a$ is irrational.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**  $-I\notin G$ can you see that????????????????

Comment: Having trouble with your keyboard?

Comment: @Joel probably having trouble with the character limit.

Comment: east or west igor is correct

Comment: just finished a 6 hour math marathon, brain is fried. please clarify.